# Powershell function failure

Tags: powershell

I swear I'm missing something easy here...

Here's a simple script to get disk info:

```
function get-disks {
try { $disks = gwmi win32_logicaldisk -co $server}
catch { write "$server : Can't connect"}
}
get-disks
$disk.deviceid
```

The gwmi command alone works perfectly. The "$disks = gwmi..." command alone works perfectly. The try {...}catch{...} lines run alone work perfectly.

But as soon as I load the function and call 'get-disks' I receive no errors, but $disks is empty.

Comment: Incidentally, I removed the try-catch out of the function and into the main body of the script and got the same non-results.

Comment: Good catch on that. But my original script has $disks.deviceid. I mis-copied it when posting this question. And now I'll edit it.

Answer (score 5):

**The `$server` parameter, and the `$disks` variable are local to the inside function and not visible (not defined) outside of the function.**

You need to provide the server name as a function parameter (from the outside in), and you need to return the `$disks` variable value from the function (from the inside out) and capture it's value.

```
function Get-Disks {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $Server
    )

    try { 
      $result = gwmi win32_logicaldisk -co $Server;
      return $result    # <--
    }
    catch { write "$Server : Can't connect"}
}

$disks = Get-Disks -Server "localhost"
```

> Note that the `$result` variable inside the function is another
>   variable the the `$disks` variable outside of the function.

For simplicity, you can write the function as follows:

```
function Get-Disks {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $Server
    )

    # just return the output of gwmi directly 
    gwmi win32_logicaldisk -co $Server;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this. Also when you call the function use `$disk = get-disks` if you want to reference the properties of it afterward (your existing code doesn't assign anything to `$disk`).

Comment: I presume returning the $disks variable changes it from a local variable in the function to a global variable the rest of the script can use, correct?

Comment: @James No, you are returning a value from the function, and catching that value in the external variable. If you didn't catch the result value, it would be caught by the console, and displayed there.

Comment: The variable inside the function can have any name you like, it won't change the mechanics. For good measure, it is advisable to not reuse variable names like this.